# Sharing with Windows 7

Tags: hard-drive, file-sharing

Here is the Issue... I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS my room mates all have windows 7 computers, I am tired of Burning CD's for them... How do I share my second HDD (Media Drive), that has all the files that always want copies of with them... In a way that they can access them from their Win7 computers?

Answer (score 0):

You can format (or create a new partition) on your second drive to NTFS, which can be
read from / written to reasonably well by both Ubuntu and Windows.

Some basic steps to do that can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition).

Comment: I have already done that... the windows machines can see the drive, but can not see the files on it.

Comment: @Puzzled Are you sure it's NTFS? Windows can't read Ubuntu's file systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could set-up a SAMBA file server on your system and then export the entire partition or whatever folders you choose as a share.

It's as easy as

`sudo apt-get install samba`

and then editing the configuration file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Check out [this simple guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html). Also it contains links to more in-depth information.